# How to convert an html string to an html object in php

Tags: php

How do i convert an html string to an html object in php like the object returned by file_get_html();

`$html_string = "<html><body>hi</body></html>"; //this returns a string`

I want to convert `$html_string` into an object and parse it using simple_html_dom

Comment: It's right there in the manual... https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_create

Comment: am use php phantomjs to  make the request and the response is an html string which i want to parse using simple_html_dom (can only parse an object).

Comment: `can only parse an object`...that's not true, where did you learn that? Did you even bother to read the link I gave?? It's literally the first example. You can also consult https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual_api.htm - again it's the first entry. Sometimes I despair...

Comment: ok have gotten  it now thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DOMDocument class. To load your HTML string to a DOM object you have to use the loadHTML method.

Then you are able to manipulate the DOM by using the DOMXPath class.
**working example**

```php
<?php
$html_string = "<html><body>hi</body></html>";
$string = <<<HTML
$html_string
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);


$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//body');
if ($result->length > 0) {
    var_dump($result->item(0)->nodeValue);
}
```